# WordPress the_content() does not show images (if not other content surrounding)

Tags: php, wordpress, image, editor

I build a custom theme for WordPress(4.4.2). I uses the standard built-in Editor to create posts. If I create a Post with, say, a headline and a paragraph AND an image, the content is shown (so is the image). But If I just type in a title and in the content area of the editor I leave JUST the image with no further text, it will not be shown on the website.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
  <div class="container-fluid site-content content-area" role="main">
    <div class="container">
      <?php if (!empty_content($post->post_content)) :?>
      <div class="content row col-md-10 xcentered">

        <?php the_content(); ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

I also tried the code without the if statement, but the_content() does not display an image without any other content.

Everything but the div.container is rendered. And as soon as I add just a single character before/after the image title, character AND image are rendered.

Any suggestions where (else) I have to make changes? Why is an image not recognized "standalone"?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Wordpress problem, but other code interfering. Is the whole <img> tag not being echo'd by the_content() or is it simply hidden by CSS/JS? Might sound too simple, but this stuff happens.

Comment: I added a bit of information to my post, .. the content (titel and image) is not rendered at all if there is no other content around the image in the editor.

Comment: Well, the first thing that springs to mind is the "empty_content" function you are using, that's a custom function. Perhaps you can post the code of that function? Seems like that is the culprit.

Comment: `function empty_content($str) { return trim(str_replace('&nbsp;','',strip_tags($str))) == '';  }` This is the code of the function. It just checks if the content is "really" empty or if there are just spaces left. I already tried to just remove the if statement and just echo "the_content()", but it has the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function 'empty_content' you are using, which you have provided in the comments on your question:

```
function empty_content($str) { 
    return trim(str_replace('&nbsp;','',strip_tags($str))) == '';
}
```

When I put `<img src="someimg.png">` into this function, it returns true, meaning your `<div>` is not rendered.

This is exactly the behavior you are describing.

Try to http://phpfiddle.org/ the following code:

```
function empty_content($str) { 
    return trim(str_replace('&nbsp;','',strip_tags($str))) == '';
}

$only_img = '<img src="someimg.png">';
$img_and_more = '<img src="someimg.png"><p>Some other stuff</p>';



var_dump(empty_content($only_img));
var_dump(empty_content($img_and_more));
```

You will see that the `$only_img` variable dumps to `true` and the `$img_and_more` dumps to false.

Comment: oh my - thanks a lot. I wrote I commented the if statement out, which I did, but in the wrong file (page.php not category.php) so I could not reproduce that it has an effect :-) Sorry.. So my custom function has to be revised because the image has no closing tag right?

Comment: Nah, it's not the closing that, it's the strip_tags that does it. It removes tags, that includes the <img> tag. Wouldn't a plain empty() and trim() do the job?

Comment: Yes will do the job - so I just do not use it anymore but did not get why the tags are not completely stripped if there are other ones too :-) maybe too late :-) thanks again

Comment: Yeah that is strange indeed. Can't explain this late either haha. Goodluck!